# Как при наведении курсора сменить картинку?

Tags: delphi

У меня есть два Image. Предположим, Image1 и Image2. Сами картинки имеют одинаковый размер. Но они находятся в двух разных местах, и Image2 имеет Visible = false. Нужно, чтобы при наведении курсора, вторая картинка приобретала координаты первой, и становилась видимой. При этом, первая картинка просто становилась не видимой. Убирая курсор от картинки, все должно приобретать то, что было до наведения курсора.

Как примерно это осуществить? Желательно подробнее и с кодом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно создать свой компонент, и в нем реализовать события OnMouseEnter и OnMouseLeave 
Надеюсь, устанавливать компоненты умеете? а если нет, то найти в гугле проще простого

А вот код класса компонента.
Вместо TImage используйте его.
И на события OnMouseEnter и OnMouseLeave выставляйте нужные вам действия.

```
unit HighlightImage;
interface
uses ExtCtrls, Messages, Controls, Classes;

type
THighlightImage = class(TImage)
private
FOnMouseEnter: TNotifyEvent;
FOnMouseLeave: TNotifyEvent;
public
procedure MouseEnter(var msg : TMessage); message CM_MOUSEENTER;
procedure MouseLeave(var msg : TMessage); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
published
property OnMouseEnter: TNotifyEvent read FOnMouseEnter write FOnMouseEnter;
property OnMouseLeave: TNotifyEvent read FOnMouseLeave write FOnMouseLeave;
end;

procedure Register;

implementation

{ THighlightImage }

procedure THighlightImage.MouseEnter(var msg: TMessage);
begin
if Assigned(FOnMouseEnter) then FOnMouseEnter(self);
end;

procedure THighlightImage.MouseLeave(var msg: TMessage);
begin
if Assigned(FOnMouseLeave) then FOnMouseLeave(self);
end;

procedure Register;
begin
RegisterComponents('ION T', [THighlightImage]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: А можно также с лейблами и всем остальным, изменив тип и название? И как изменять картинку обратно при убирании курсора?

Answer (score 0):

1. Вешаетесь обработчик на событие onmouseover(ну или аналог почитайте доку по VCL) Image1, на котором выставляете визибл у image2, left и top. Ну и обратное действие на Onmouseout( onmouseexit может такое не помню точно)
2. Кладёте на форму веб браузер и задаёте вопрос про html :-)

Comment: вот в чем проблема, так это в том, что у TImage такого события, на "покидание мышки" нету...

Comment: Если нет, то только в паблике. Вариант с наследование это гуд, только вот я бы не на сообщения вешался а на переопределения протектед метода. Хотя суть одна и та же

Comment: Да с компонентом, самый простой и доступный вариант..

Answer (score 0):

Ничего особого не надо делать. Просто в обработчик картинки MouseMove напишите

```
Image1.Visible:=false;
Image2.Visible:=true;
```

А на в обработчике формы MouseMove напишите

```
Image1.Visible:=true;
Image2.Visible:=false;
```

Вот и всё.